# How to identify fonts in iOS apps, from iOS?

Tags: fonts, ios

Often I want to find out what font I'm seeing in an iOS app. And I want to do it without going to a computer. Is there a way to do this?

I know there's the great WhatTheFont website, but that requires taking a screenshot and carefully snipping out the text and uploading the snipped image of the text alone. I don't know any apps that can help with that workflow.

I know there's also the WhatTheFont Safari extension on iOS8, but that's only good for identifying fonts in web pages and I'm wondering about apps.

Comment: ...I dont know anything about iPhones/iOS but on my Droid I hold the down volume key and power button to take a screenshot, it tells me a screenshot was taken, I open it in the Photo app and can crop it. It took me less than a minute to screenshot, crop, and upload an image to WhatTheFont on my phone. All of this is default on Android. I can't imagine iOS doesn't have this ability

Comment: Snapseed on iOS can handle that workflow, I believe (at least the cropping part)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an app for that: [WhatTheFont Mobile](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/mobile/). You can take a new photo or select one from your local "camera roll", select the area to be recognized, and after selecting the letters it contacts WTF and reports the results back.

Taking a snapshot of any running app is done by holding down the Home button and then clicking the Sleep button once. A camera click sound and a flash indicates the screen got saved.

A minor drawback for me is the WTF app is designed for iPhones: the 'select area' part is a bit small on my iPad.

Answer (score 1):

First thing to say: I'm the programmer/designer of the app I present bellow.
Second thing to say: if you try it, you'll agree it's the best & easiest solution! :) 

A few days ago, we released [Find my Font mobile](https://www.findmyfont.com/download/download-mobile-edition) - a free app for both iOS & Android - which identifies any free or commercial font from an image.

 So, if you want to identify the fonts of an iOS app:

a) You take a screen capture of the app
b) You run the Find my Font app and load the screen capture
c) You select 1-7 distinct letters
d) You can optionally choose a font category (you can target your search to "All Fonts", "Freemium", "Commercial" or "Google Fonts")
e) You tap on search button and get the 30 closest font matches

Take a look at the screenshots bellow, for an example of finding the closest matches of a book cover using Adobe Garamond.

Happy font hunting! :)
I'll be glad to respond to any questions or suggestions on how to make the app even better.

PS: The WhatTheFont app mentioned above is an excellent one but it only matches fonts that MyFonts.com is selling. Find my Font matches any commercial or free font (like fonts of dafont.com and Google Web Fonts).

[image: FmF Mobile Screenshots]